# Laravel custom Request validation not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to use form Laravel Request validation by creating custom form request. Here is my code snippet

#### api.php

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'User'], function () {
  Route::put('user/{user}', 'UpdateUserGeneralInfoController@UpdateUserGeneralInfo');
});
```

#### UpdateUserGeneralInfoController.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\User\UpdateUserGeneralInfoRequest;

class UpdateUserGeneralInfoController extends Controller
{
   public function UpdateUserGeneralInfo(UpdateUserGeneralInfoRequest $request,User $user)
   {
      $user->name = $request->name;
      $user->email = $request->email;
      $user->date_of_birth = $request->date_of_birth;
      $user->save();

      $response = [
          'message' => 'User info updated successfully'
      ];

      return response($response, 201);

    }
 }
```

#### UpdateUserGeneralInfoRequest.php

```
namespace App\Http\Requests\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdateUserGeneralInfoRequest extends FormRequest
{
  public function authorize()
  {
     return true;    
  }

  public function rules()
  {
     return [
        'name' => 'required|max:50',
        'email' => 'required',
        'date_Of_birth' => 'required'
     ];
  }

  public function messages()
  {
    return [
        'name.required' => 'Name is required',
        'email.required' => 'An email is required',
        'date_Of_birth' => 'Date of Birth is required'
    ];
  }
}
```

The folder structure is

[image]

I am trying to test the request through Postman. So here is my json input

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name":"Osman Rafi",
  "email": "rafi@devport.com",
  "current_address": "House-26,Islampur R/A, Mejortila, Sylhet-3100,Bangladesh",
  "bio": "But a man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed,but not defeated.",
  "linkedin": "linkedin.com/in/osman-goni-chowdhury-bb421a16b",
  "facebook": "https://www.facebook.com/osman.rafi140",
  "github": "https://github.com/Osman-Rafi",
  "blood_group": "O(+ve)",
  "password": "111111"
}
```

It showing me

```
404 | Not Found
```

It work perfectly if I try this is controller

```
public function UpdateUserGeneralInfo(Request $request,User $user)
{
}
```

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` and compare the route your `PUT`ing to from `PostMan` to the output. Also make sure you have a row in your `users` table with an `id` of 1. 404 here can mean either route not found or no User record for the given ID.

Comment: Typo: `$request->date_of_birth` in your Controller, `'date_Of_birth'` in your form request

Comment: Did you use the `api` prefix in postman?

Comment: User table has a row with id 1, route & postman url are same, api prefix is also added but the porblem is still there

Comment: it seems you are redirected when validation fails and that causes a 404. what happens if you pass the validation??

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass all these 3 variables in the request (you are missing date_Of_birth):

```
'name' => 'required|max:50',
'email' => 'required',
'date_Of_birth' => 'required'
```

However, I think your error comes from few other places because 404 not found comes from the route not being found in the link.

have you cleared the route cache after adding the route you are calling:

try

> php artisan route:cache

also add

```
'name.required' => 'Name is required',
'email.required' => 'An email is required',
'date_Of_birth' => 'Date of Birth is required'
```

**date_Of_birth.required**

Comment: tried but doesn't work. If I replace ``UpdateUserGeneralInfoRequest``  with ``Request``

Comment: did you check if you are sending a put request?

Comment: yeah. and here is the postman request ``http://localhost:8000/api/user/1``

Comment: Please make sure that you have added "date_Of_birth" in your request data "O" is a capital letter. Now I see add .required to in the messages function in the request 'date_Of_birth' => 'Date of Birth is required'

Comment: If you have debugging enabled, youll be shown more details about the error. Also, do check if you are sending Accept application/json header. (Enven without you should see full error bad if debug.is set to true)